# New Green Card holder health insurance?

Tags: usa, greencard, indian-citizens, health-insurance, health-care

My mom recently became a green card holder. What is the best health insurance I can get for her?

From what I see, visitor's coverage is the only one that is can be seen using Google but I am not sure if it is right for her.

We live in Seattle, WA. Her home country is India.

Comment: I suspect your question may be closed as opinion-based or too broad unless you can refine it. What do you mean by ‘best’ and ‘right for her’, for example?

Comment: @Traveller  Thanks for your reply. So, for example, if you go to her home country she'll be able to tell you about the top 3 companies that have a reputation for providing good health insurances but I don't see anything like that in US for Green Card holders. I guess any links that would lead to a reputable source for health insurance for a person with a green card is what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Your mom can buy a plan from her state's health insurance exchange (Obamacare/ACA marketplace). The one for Washington state is [Washington Healthplanfinder](https://www.wahealthplanfinder.org/). Although this year's open enrollment period already ended, one qualifies for a 60-day special enrollment period after a life-changing event; one such event is moving to the US, so your mom should be able to enroll if she moved to the US in the last 60 days. If her household income is below 400% of the federal poverty level, she will receive a subsidy to help pay part of the premium.